# Logical AND in ternary operator in C

Tags: c, ternary-operator, logical-operators, logical-and

I am trying to find the maximum and minimum of 3 integers (var1,var2,var3) in C.To make things slighty interesting I am writing the logic in 1 line.

```
(var1>var2)?((var1>var3)?(max=var1):(max=var3)&&(min=var2)):((var2>var3)?(max=var2):(max=var3)&&(min=var1));
```

To make debugging easier, here is the boring version in several lines

```
(var1>var2)?
    ((var1>var3)?
        (max=var1):
        (max=var3)&&(min=var2)
    ):
    ((var2>var3)?
     (max=var2):
     (max=var3)&&(min=var1)
    );
```

The logical AND is not being executed ,min is returning garbage value.
Help.

Comment: To make things **convoluted**, you're writing it on one line.

Comment: First step to help yourself is to split the single line into several to simplify analysing it.

Comment: My test partially works. If you initialise `min` and `max` with sentinel values it might make it easier to track the problem, instead of getting "garbage".

Comment: In the boring version you can quite clearly see that the min assignment will not happen if max is 0. Does that fit your test cases which fail?

Comment: Otherwise, there are cases e.g. var1 being max, in which there is simply no code for assigning anything to min.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the boring version:

```
(var1>var2)?
    ((var1>var3)?
        (max=var1): // nothing gets assigned to min
        (max=var3)&&(min=var2) // nothing gets assigned to min, if var3==0
    ):
    ((var2>var3)?
     (max=var2): // nothing gets assigned to min
     (max=var3)&&(min=var1) // nothing gets assigned to min, if var3==0
    );
```

You can see that in many cases nothing gets assigned to `min`.